# Is ISR 4451 hotplugable

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-isr

For a ISR4451 there is a SM-D-ES3G-48-P Module, is this module hotplugable or should I power down the ISR for install the SM Module?

**UPDATE**

```
sh hw-module all attribute
Slot 0 Bay 0 Board 0 Module[ISR4451-X-4x1GE] spa_type 0x76E Daughter Board Not Present
Basic attributes : length 11, version [2], module-type [ngio-virtual], width [unknown]
Power Rating [0], Control Endpoint count [0], Daughter Board Count [0]
KR Support [0x00], 16-bit GPIO [Not present], Submodule reset support [Not required]

Extended Attributes for [Front Panel 4 ports Gigabitethernet Module]
Port Count 4 Per-port Information : Type [Ethernet] Max IID [0] Connector [RJ45] Network clocking [disable]
Module OID: 1 3 6 1 4 1 9 12 3 1 9 92 21
Port OID: 1 3 6 1 4 1 9 12 3 1 10 109
```

Comment: Even with hot-swapable hardware, you _must_ be prepared for something to go wrong, and for the device to need to be restarted. That does happen with some regularity. We have decided to never depend on the OIR claim, and we will always shut down a device to insert or remove cards, and it has proven much more reliable.

Comment: This was also my first thought, but I didn't know the best practice for that task. So I will shutdown the ISR for insert the SM.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enhanced Ethernet modules on ISR are hot swapable, but please note you need to Use the **hw-module slot <1-4> oir-stop** command when removing or replacing a hot-swappable Cisco enhanced EtherSwitch service module duringonline insertion and removal (OIR).

Comment: Which ID is for the SM Module Slot? Is double wide module. The output of sh hw-module all attribute don't show any SM double wide slot. I want to first install this module.

Comment: you can find the ID easily from the output of show version, or show ip interface brief

Comment: the module isn't attached now, I try to install this module the first time and do now know to shutdown the ISR or plug it into the Router while the ISR is running.

Comment: As per cisco this module support OIR (online insertion and removal) but you should decide the slot number and run the mentioned command first